# How to access remote private Msmq on workgroup windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, queue, msmq

as mentioned in the title of this post that I am having issues in connecting to a remote private msmq queue on windows 7 machine on workgroup.

I created a local queue and system is working and am able to succesfully queue my messages in the local queue but when I try to connect to a remote queue to queue my message i am unable to access it.

Both msmq services are installed on windows 7 machine and trying to access it using winforms c#.
I tried so many blogs but dont know what I am missing. This is the error message I am receiving

> Access to Message Queuing system is denied

and this is what I am using to connect to remote queue

> FormatName:Direct=OS:machinename\private$\TestQueue

I also tried to give the ipaddress as well like this but no help

> FormatName:Direct=TCP:ipaddress\private$\TestQueue

I have gone through lots of blogs but nothing helped.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to connect with the same transaction configuration as the remote queue? In other words, if the remote queue is transactional,  your connection should be also, and vice versa.

Comment: No, none of the queues are transactional

Comment: Right-click the queue, Properties, Security tab.  Assign rights to the Everyone group.

Comment: Hans, already assigned the rights to the everyone group, but no use

Comment: Incorrect - it should be Everyone + Anonymous Logon. Everyone has not meant "everyone" for many years.

Comment: John, i have already given Everyone + Anonymouse logon full access...but no help

Answer (score 0):

if you try to write to a remote queue, an outgoing queue is created on your machine locally. check out the permissions on this outgoing queue and see if there are any items in the outgoing queue. maybe the problem is not the remote machine

Comment: "check out the permissions on this outgoing queue" - that is not something you can do. An outgoing queue has no permissions you can view like a public or private queue.

Comment: dotnetPr0, there is outgoing queue but there is not option where I can see its security settings.

Comment: john, how can i see the security settings on the outgoing queue

Comment: right John, you in fact cannot do it :(. Shax can you see any messages in your outgoing queue when you try to write them into the remote queue? perhaps windows firewall is blocking the connection, take a look at this: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2009/06/15/msmq-and-the-windows-firewall.aspx)

Comment: dotnetPr0. i am looking into the article, but no I dont see any message in the outgoing queue. I double checked that